# Doubts of CONSECUTIVE "Unallocated" spaces HD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have this HD partition.

[image]

I want to know:

- If it is normal to have two consecutive "Unallocated" space?
  What sense does it?

  You can see I have two:

  1. 162.35GB
  2. The Right Side of the first Unallocated. (Narrow)

I have another Disk without this LAST Free Space (Unallocated)!!!
[image]

I'm NOT asking -how merge consecutive partition?-, I asking if is normal have two consecutive "Unallocated" spaces in HD (is different question).

This [How can I merge two unallocated spaces?](https://superuser.com/questions/581192/how-can-i-merge-two-unallocated-spaces) is not answer for my question...

Comment: Moab, I was trying to manipulate the last "unallocated" partitions (join), for me is strange two CONSECUTIVE "unallocated" parititons, because conceptually a "unallocated" parititon is lot or part of space without format, you have only One space (not two/three), Separately obviously (can exist multiple free spaces).

Now, The second question follows from the first.
- How Can I (if it is possible) merge these consecutive "Unallocated" partitions?

Comment: This isn't quite the same as Moab's link, where the unallocated spaces were not adjacent. In this case, the tiny space on the end of the disc is probably a rounding remainder, depending on the how the disc was originally formatted. It is only a few MB, and not worth worrying about.

Comment: I having problem to install CentOS, because the biggest  "free space" is Not detected... I was thinking that is a problem of Windows  when made the partitions...

Comment: I've not installed CentOS, but I've had Little trouble with Ubuntu, which seems to have found free space without difficulty. You could try allocating a partition without formatting, then tell CentOS to install there (Ubuntu allows this, but CentOS may not).